# Error when login to Docker container using Molecule

Tags: docker, ansible, molecule

I have this Molecule configuration:

```
---
dependency:
  name: galaxy
driver:
  name: docker
platforms:
  - name: instance1
    image: docker.io/pycontribs/centos:8
provisioner:
  name: ansible
verifier:
  name: ansible
```

I run `molecule converge` and it works fine. Now, I need to log into the `instance1` container. When I run `molecule login --host instance1`, I get this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/bin/env
> docker exec -e COLUMNS=108 -e LINES=41 -e TERM=bash -e TERM=xterm -ti
> instance1 bash'

What is happening?

**Versions**

docker package: 5.0.3

molecule: 3.6.1

molecule-docker: 1.1.0

**NOTE**

If I run the command that is getting an error:

```
/usr/bin/env docker exec -e COLUMNS=108 -e LINES=41 -e TERM=bash -e TERM=xterm -ti instance1 bash
```

in a terminal, it works fine.

Comment: The error message is very common when systems confuse "shell" expansion versus "exec" expansion; it is trying to run a command named `/usr/bin/env docker exec...` versus trying run the command `/usr/bin/env`, with _arguments_ `"docker", "exec", "-e",...`; regrettably, with so little specifics in your question, no one can give you more concrete advice other than to read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page,
and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with molecule not correctly expanding the shell arguments and has been fixed in this pull request: https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule/pull/3468

I've patched this pull request into my local molecule instance and can confirm it fixes this.